# Tiempos verbales

Tags: tiempos-verbales

> "Pablo Ruiz Picasso, nacido en Málaga en 1881, comenzó a pintar desde muy temprana edad, mostrando ya una habilidad extraordinaria. Después de trabajar en Barcelona, se trasladó a Paris a comienzos de siglo. Allí recibió la influencia de los pintores franceses del momento. Picasso **reaccionaría** pronto antes aquellas influencias y **empezaría** a crear sus primeras obras famosas, en lo que se **conoció** como periodo azul y periodo rosa dentro de su carrera artística."

¿Por qué usa la condicional en vez del pretérito?

Ese párrafo es de Josefa Martín García.

¿Es el uso del pretérito correcto para el verbo conocer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es difícil de explicar con qué lógica el idioma llegó a esto, pero sí, el modo condicional también sirve para hablar del **tiempo futuro con respecto a un tiempo pasado, que a su vez es pasado con respecto a un tiempo futuro**.

> Picasso **reaccionaría** pronto ante aquellas influencias...

significa que la reacción de Picasso ocurrió después del presente de la narración (principios de siglo), pero antes del presente de la lectura (hoy).

Comment: Menos mal que no ha preguntado sobre el condicional perfecto, un tiempo pasado con respeto a un tiempo posterior a un tiempo pasado más anterior al del otro tiempo pasado ;)

Comment: Tengo una otra pregunta, es el uso del pretérito para el verbo conocer correcto?

Comment: @AmandaKelius: sí, está correcto

Comment: @guifa, mi sistema nervioso tiene limitaciones... ¿me das un ejemplo de ese engendro (el condicional perfecto)?

Comment: @Rodrigo «Llegué a Londres el lunes.  Habría ido a Glasgow antes de volver a Madrid, pero gasté todo mi dinero».  El tiempo de referencia es la llegada a Londres (por eso hay que incluir tiempos pasados).  El segundo tiempo de referencia es la vuelta a Madrid que es posterior a la llegada, por eso usamos el condicional.  Pero el viaje a Glasgow iba a ser antes de dicha vuelta, y para referir a tiempos pasados según alguna referencia temporal, usamos el aspecto perfecto.

Comment: Así el viaje a Glasgow se sitúa ser antes de la vuelta a Madrid (que, por cierto, podría ser antes o después de ahora mismo) que a su vez se sitúa después de la llegada a Londres, que se se sitúa antes del momente presente.

Comment: @guifa, OK, muchas gracias. Es bastante impresionante que hagamos todos esos cálculos y anotaciones automáticamente basándonos en dos palabritas.