# Uso del tiempo condicional o el pretérito

Tags: tiempos-verbales

> Hacia 1907, la muerte de Cézanne y las influencias del arte africano
>   **dar** paso a un nuevo cambio en el pintor, su época negra, que **daría** a una de sus más geniales" creaciones: el cubismo.

Estas frases son de Josefa Martín García.

Creo que el tiempo verbal del primer verbo, "dar", es el pretérito. ¿Es correcto?
¿El tiempo verbal del segundo verbo es el condicional porque [habla del "tiempo futuro con respecto a un tiempo pasado"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10381/5481)?

Comment: ¿Creo que debe ser **dio** paso, no?

Comment: @guifa si, señora.

Comment: I  think it's «_**dan** paso_», it seems a typo or an [OCR](http://wpdia.com.ar/n,z3) error ("dar" it's optically similar to "dan"). In the way it's write **it has no sense**.

Comment: Here the original text: https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130330104601AAC6XB9

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be like this:

> "Hacia 1907, la muerte de Cézanne y las influencias del arte africano DAN paso a un nuevo cambio en el pintor, su época negra, que DIÓ a una de sus más geniales creaciones: el cubismo."

however, the time that was written is crucial, the spanish in 1700-1800-1900 is really different from the spanish that we can see today.

Also, and this is for Diego:

> "Ayer llega mi compañero de piso del trabajo, da un portazo y se mete en su habitación. Luego sale y empieza a quejarse de todo."

This sentence is correct but almost 90% of the people instead of saying "Ayer llega" says

> " Ayer llegó mi compañero de piso del trabajo, dió un portazo y se metió en su habitación. Luego salió y empezó a quejarse de todo."

Comment: I agree.  Probably it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría "dieron", pero en el caso del primer verbo podrías usar también lo que se llama "presente histórico". El presente histórico consiste en en hablar de acciones en el pasado usando el tiempo presente.

> Durante la segunda guerra púnica Anibal cruza los alpes y desafía al Imperio Romano.
>
> Ayer llega mi compañero de piso del trabajo, da un portazo y se mete en su habitación. Luego sale y empieza a quejarse de todo.

Así que puedes usar el presente en con el primer verbo y decir:

> Hacia 1907, la muerte de Cézanne y las influencias del arte africano **dan** paso a un nuevo cambio en el pintor, su época negra, que daría a una de sus más geniales creaciones: el cubismo

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que *dar* es, en realidad, *dan*; tal vez un fallo de escaneo. Es lo más coherente: se usa el presente y luego el condicional para expresar algo que sucede en el futuro respecto a ese presente (para nosotros, todo está en el pasado).

Comment: «Dan» sí que encaja, pero entonces yo usaría luego «dará». «Daría» es el el tiempo futuro con respecto a un tiempo pasado, como dice @user6979, y por tanto creo que lo que debería precederle es «dieron».