# Uso del tiempo verbales condicional y pretérito

Tags: tiempos-verbales

> > "Después del cubismo, Picasso volvió a una época clásica a partir de 1914. En esta nueva etapa, la principal temática **sería** el desnudo femenino grandioso, pesado, alejado de la excesiva delgadez de sus anteriores arlequines. Picasso alternaría el cubismo con el clasicismo."

Este párrafo es de Josefa Martin Garcia.

¿Por qué usa el condicional (**sería**) en vez del imperfecto?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tiempos verbales](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10378/tiempos-verbales)

Comment: @rsanchez, you are right. Since the other question is from the same user, I'll edit this one so it asks just about "condicional en vez del imperfecto" and not "condicional en vez del pretérito" which is in her other question.

Comment: ese es precisamente el uso del tiempo imperfecto, para definir cosas que podrían ser y no fueron, o cosas que en aquel momento estaban en duda.

Answer (score 4):

El condicional se usa en narraciones como esta para expresar un hecho que para nosotros está en el pasado (total o parcialmente), pero para el momento de la narración está en el futuro. Es decir: cuando Picasso volvió a la época clásica en 1914, esa etapa todavía no había comenzado.

En este tipo de construcciones, el condicional se puede sustituir por la perífrasis *iba a + infinitivo*:

> En esta nueva etapa, la principal temática *iba a ser* el desnudo femenino grandioso [...]

Comment: De hecho, el condicional salió de la construcción [verbo en infinitivo] + [ir en imperfecto] como *ser ía* (antes de la apariencia de la *b* en las conjugaciones, *cf.* con el verbo en portugués que mantiene las conjugaciones con solo *ia*).  Es efectivamente lo mismo que pasó con el futuro que salió de [verbo en infinitivo] + [haber en presente]

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi humilde punto de vista ese postpretérito condicional indica algo que pudo haber sido y no fué.
Es mejor desde mi punto de vista usar el pasado cuando es pasado: " el resultado fué el desnudo femenino grandioso"  quizá es menos "elegante" pero es descriptivo y no se presta a confusión.

Comment: "Fue" no lleva tilde, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Ese "sería" se refiere a algo que ocurrirá a partir de 1914, porque la narración se ha situado en ese punto.